# How do I encrypt a text file by iterating through two chars at a time, finding them in an array and swapping the cols they are in with each other?

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that will read in a text file, remove any spaces, full stops, commas, or anything that isn't a letter, and then store the resulting characters into a character array. It would then iterate through the characters two at a time. It would then take these two characters and locate them in an array, "swap" them with two other characters, and then print out those characters. The array in question is a two-dimensional array.

The array has four distinct quadrants; the top left and bottom right have the characters A - Z (excluding J) in an ordered sequence, and the top right and bottom left have the characters A - Z (excluding J) in an unordered sequence. The program is meant to find the two characters within the ordered quadrants (the first letter corresponds with the top left quadrant and the second letter corresponds with the bottom right quadrant). Based on the positions of these two letters, it would then find corresponding letters in the other two quadrants by swapping the columns of *"P"* and *"O"*:

> **'P'**, 'W', 'D', 'R', **'C'**,
>
> 'U', 'Y', 'K', 'E', 'Q',
>
> 'Z', 'X', 'V', 'S', 'B',
>
> 'D', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D',
>
> 'A', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I',
>
> **'V'**, 'L', 'M', 'N', **'O',**

As you can see from this sample of the array, by swapping the column the *"P"* is located in with the column that *"O"* is located in, and vice versa, and then going to the same rows, you are able to find the encryption.

I am having trouble with the encryption part. The program is able to read in the text file and remove anything that isn't a character with a regex, and store the characters into a character array. The logic for dealing with characters two at a time is also done, I feel. I have tried using nested for loops to (twice) to see if the matrix at position [i][j] is equal to the first character (x) and then again to the second character (y). Is there a good to do what I'm trying to do? Do I need to use a List? And if so, what kind? Below is my code so far:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class FourSquareCipher {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        char[][] matrix = { 
                { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E',  'Z', 'G', 'P', 'T', 'F' },
                { 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K',  'O', 'I', 'H', 'M', 'U' },
                { 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P',  'W', 'D', 'R', 'C', 'N' },
                { 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U',  'Y', 'K', 'E', 'Q', 'A' },
                { 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z',  'X', 'V', 'S', 'B', 'L' },
                { 'M', 'F', 'N', 'B', 'D',  'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' },
                { 'C', 'R', 'H', 'S', 'A',  'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'K' },
                { 'X', 'Y', 'O', 'G', 'V',  'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P' },
                { 'I', 'T', 'U', 'E', 'W',  'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U' },
                { 'L', 'Q', 'Z', 'K', 'P',  'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' } 
                };

        String fileName = "PoblachtNaHEireann.txt";
        String line = null;
        int bigram = 0;
        int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0;
        int i, j;
        char x = 0, y = 0;
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long startTimeSeconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(startTime);

        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);       
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);


        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            char[] fileToChar = line.replaceAll("(?:--|[\\[\\]{}(),.-: +/\\\\])", "").toUpperCase().toCharArray();

            for (char fileArray:fileToChar) {
                System.out.print(fileArray);
            }

            for (i = 0; i < line.length(); i += 2) {
                x = line.charAt(bigram);
                y = line.charAt(bigram + 1);
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Encryption time (s): " + ((System.currentTimeMillis() - startTimeSeconds) / 1000000000 / 1000));
        bufferedReader.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your solution is correct, but you can do it faster using simple maths. Consider this code (`chr` is character you want to find in matrix):

```
int code = ((int)chr<(int)'J') ? (int)chr-(int)'A' : (int)chr-(int)'A'-1;
int row = code/5;
int col = code%5;
```

You first compute ordinal number of letter (i.e. A=0, B=1, C=2, ..., I=8, K=9 etc.). Then you can get row and column (in upper-left square) by simple maths operations. If you want lower-right square, you just add 5 to both variables.

EDIT: You can do this even faster. Just pre-comp (manually, as it's not difficult) all possible results:

```
int[] row_info = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 42, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
int[] col_info = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 42, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4};
```

And then:

```
int code = (int)chr - 65;
int row = row_info[code];
int col = col_info[code];
```

Comment: Where would you reference `matrix` here?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking about. Did you mean 'where did I used `matrix` in codes written above?' or 'how can I reference `matrix` after computing these values?'?

Comment: I didn't use it directly. Instead, I used it before writing program, and now I use only some conclusions. In the first example, I noticed that letters in upper-left square form regular pattern, which can be described by division and modulo. In the second one, I simply pre-computed results for all letters. Some kind of inverse array.